# how to get the sql horizontal database values vertically using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatables

i have a table in sql server like as follows

```
studentid     subject    marks
    1          telugu      70
    1         english      80
    1           maths       90
    1           social      70
```

i want to display the above table in gridview as follows

```
 studentid   telugu   english   maths   social    total 
    1            70       80         90      70      310
```

i tried using datatable using as follows

i created datacolumns dynamically as follows

```
while (dr.Read())
            {
               dt.Columns.Add(dr["subname"].ToString(), typeof(string));
            }
```

but not getting idea to insert marks dynamically shown like above...

thanks in advance.... 
please help me...

Comment: look at pivot tables

Comment: You can do it by pivoting as Urili said but do you have certain amount of subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing that using `CASE`

```
 SELECT studentid
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'telugu' THEN marks END) AS telugu
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'english' THEN marks END) AS english
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'maths' THEN marks END) AS maths
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'social' THEN marks END) AS social
        ,SUM(marks) AS Total
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY studentid
```

Comment: how to get total for the above using sql

Comment: @Ramya you asked for total of subjects, you just need to add `,SUM(marks) AS Total` in the `SELECT`. Look at the updated answer

Comment: @ sqluser   i already used that query and i am getting the sum of all student marks not the individual one....

Comment: because there is no column for total marks in the database i want to add each subject values dynamically and display it as total

Comment: This should show the total marks of each student as it's grouped by studentId. Show me your desired output so I can help.

Comment: i used select sum(marks)  instead of sum(marks) now i got solved it... thanks your immediate response.... thank you very much

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using pivot (solution from DB side) :

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('Example','U') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE Example
CREATE TABLE Example (studentid INT,subject VARCHAR(30), marks INT)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES
(1,'telugu',70),
(1,'english',80),
(1,'maths',90),
(1,'social',70),
(2,'telugu',70),
(2,'english',80),
(2,'maths',90),
(2,'social',70)

SELECT studentid,[telugu],[english],[maths],[social] FROM Example
PIVOT
(
    MAX(marks)
    FOR subject IN ([telugu],[english],[maths],[social])
) AS pvt
```